# How to get the ListView SplitButton Position?

Tags: listview, delphi, winapi

I try to develop a ListView, like used in the Windows Explorer. I want to offer a SplitButton ... and if the user click on it, a popup window should be shown:

[image]

How can I figure out the left edge of the SplitButton? Or how can I figure out the width of the SplitButton - the right edge I know from the column width...

Comment: this is not `ListView` but `DirectUIHWND`

Comment: @RbMm: Thank you. But the ListView has that SplitButtons too...

Comment: I'd go with SM_CXVSCROLL.

Comment: @RbMm Apparently `DirectUIHWND` is the container, but if you dig down then you will find system treeview and listview controls.

Comment: [Header_GetItemDropDownRect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775395(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @RbMm: YES! That's the answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You need an instance for that. What if there're no explorer windows? What if explorer is not the shell?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: Requiring *Explorer* to be the shell is no real restriction. It is the only supported shell for Windows.

Comment: The OP is not trying to interact with Explorer; they want to make their own program that has the same functionality as Explorer.

Comment: @IInspectable - I don't know what you mean by a supported shell, the OS supports replacing the shell.

Comment: @and - How are you going to call Header_GetItemDropDownRect without interacting with an explorer window?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: The `Header_GetItemDropDownRect` API call does not ask for an Explorer window. It's part of the header control API. Besides, Shell replacements may have been a supported scenario in Windows 2000. To my knowledge, there is no officially supported Shell Replacement SDK or documentation available.

Comment: @IInspectable - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/commercialize/customize/enterprise/shell-launcher

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: Exactly like I said: There *"is no officially supported Shell Replacement SDK or documentation"*. Whatever, this is not related to this question anyway.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz you can create your own listview headers; that is a separate control. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775238(v=vs.85).aspx There is also [a message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774937(v=vs.85).aspx) for getting the header from an existing listview, for scenarios in which the listview APIs that deal with the headers aren't sufficient.

Comment: @IIns - You don't need a sdk. The shell is any application you can use for that purpose. As the document I linked says, a command window for instance.. And I don't know what you mean by supported. It is irrelevant yes, I've misunderstood the question.

Comment: @and - Yes, thanks, I know. I misunderstood the question as what is required is the width of the arrow in an explorer window.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: Yes, I understand. But this is not officially supported. There are no contracts the replacement application needs to implement. And when things go boom, Microsoft support isn't going to help. In other words: It's not a supported scenario. You linked to documentation that explains, that this is possible. This is a different issue. Anyway, completely unrelated to the question anyway. Shall we leave it at that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RbMm gave the answer as comment: [Header_GetItemDropDownRect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775395.aspx).